# How to get the process id of eclipse's current workspace?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, pid

I need to know the process id of eclipse for current workspace. Suppose there are 3 eclipse opened in 3 different workspace like workspace1,workspace2 and workspace3. I want to run a java program in worksapce1 to get the process id of workspace1. Is there any way to get this? I can figure out the process id of all running eclipse by the below command:

```
String strCommand = "wmic process where name='eclipse.exe' get ProcessID";
ArrayList<String> pidList = runCommand(strCommand); 


public ArrayList<String> runCommand(String arguments)
{
    String[] cmd = new String[3];
    ArrayList<String> output = new ArrayList<>();
    cmd[0] = "cmd";
    cmd[1] = "/c";
    cmd[2] = arguments;

    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);
    Process process;
    builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
    try
    {
        process = builder.start();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while (true)
        {
            line = bufferedReader.readLine();
            if (line == null) { break; }
            output.add(line);
            //System.out.println(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return output;
}
```

I have also tried with jnr-4.5.0.jar and jna-platform-4.5.0.jar to get the process id like below:

```
 int pid = Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetCurrentProcessId();
```

Every time it shows a random pid which is actually not match with the process id of eclipse that i found from windows task manager.

**Is there any way to get the process id for current workspace?**

**N.B: I'm using java 8 and windows platform.**

**Thank you.**

Comment: You would probably have to search the process's open files list to see which workspace directory .metadata it is reading. No idea how you do that on Windows (`lsof` on macOS or Linux)

Comment: What do you need it for?

Comment: @Kayaman I have developed a eclipse plugin where i have load a dll by using Native.loadLibrary(). It's working properly but there is problem if i call any method which have to use dll class. If i close eclipse it's run as a background process instead of closing completely. And i have found that this problem is occurred if i only call dll class. I didn't find any proper way to unload dll.

Comment: For different workspaces, different javaw.exe processes gets opened in task manager. Instead of using "name='eclipse.exe'", use "name='javaw.exe'". Checked also.

Comment: @Aman javaw.exe also showed random pid which is not equal to pid of eclipse.exe. I need pid of eclipse to stop the eclipse process manually.

Comment: I have checked 6-7 times with different eclipse versions and workspaces and always found the same ID which is being shown in task manager. Are u sure? Used eclipse versions: helios, mars and oxygen

Comment: @Aman My eclipse version Neon.2 Release (4.6.2) and my pc is windows10-64 bit. Now i'm telling you my current situations. I have run eclipse.exe and found the PID from windows task manager suppose 7204. If i run the above command as you suggest "javaw.exe instead of eclipse.exe" it shows 6704 and it's give random id for every run of the above command. But if i run my existing command it shows 7204. Did you got my problem? I can find the exact pid of every eclipse.exe but i'm unable to detect the exact pid for current workspace. Thank you.

Comment: Brother, when you run multiple programs from different workspace from a "single eclipse IDE", u will get "only 1 eclipse PID" and "multiple" programs' PIDs. U are saying in a multiple run, this is giving different PIDs for "multiple" programs' but this is not happening with me. What different I can see is eclipse version. So try to change eclipse version also and see same is happening or not.